# bootstrap toggle tab has does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I am currently helping to solve a toggle problem but there's no error showing in console and I don't know where to start looking.
There are two tabs which can be toggled between each other.  Let's say toggle tabs are pay / method.  Default page is showing pay and when method tab is clicked, method tab shows perfectly but when clicking pay again the tab (CSS) worked fine that we can see pay tab is active but contents of pay doesn't show.  The contents are still method.

Currently using bootstrap and of course the script included jquery already.

The html code is

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li class="active" role="presentation">
<a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="home" href="#home" aria-expanded="true">Pay</a>
<li class="" role="presentation">
<a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" aria-controls="method" href="#method" aria-expanded="false">method</a>
</ul>
```

I am not sure what else to show since the scripts is form bootstrap, it'll be HUGE.

P.S. as said, even though the contents don't show but by clicking each other, I can still see the class is set to active and aria-expanded is set to true to whichever tab I clicked. (Also, I am wondering if I couldn't find out what is really causing this since there are no errors and so on, am I able to write a new script and include the script below the bootstrap script?  That should override and work right?)

Edit:
I have tried adding jquery and so I can select the current element but somehow it only worked a bit.
I added another class into the html

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active payment-tabs"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="payment">pay</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="payment-tabs"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-id="profile">method</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have script like this

```
$("ul.nav.nav-tabs").on('click', $(".payment-tabs.active"), function () {
    console.log($(".payment-tabs.active"));
});
```

I tried `console.log` lots ways to find the current element or at least the a element but when I console.log I realized when I click method, the `console.log` does give the element of `method` but when I click `pay` the first time what I got from `console.log` is still the `method` element even though `pay` already has `active` class added.  If I click the `pay` again then I will finally get the `pay` element.  I might have an idea of the reason but I just have no idea how I can solve this.

Can someone please give me a hand please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you include the scripts needed to run the code. See the running demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4jqp8ytp/1/)

Basically, you just need to call 3 main sources.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

The Tab

```
<div class="container">     
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a data-target="#payment" data-toggle="tab">Payment</a></li>
    <li><a data-target="#method" data-toggle="tab">Method</a></li>
  </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="payment">This is a payment area</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="method">This is a method.</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes I do have those scripts included which I was curious why it's not working properly too.  the default is payment when I click to method, the content changes to method perfectly but when I click payment again, the li add / remove classes correctly but the content would still in method content and not changing to payment area

Comment: Does the tabs run without  adding custom jquery? Maybe also check the positions of your scripts. the jquery link should be on the top of all js scripts.

Comment: omg it's actually the `data-target` but why would the tab work the first time from payment to method just won't be the other way around

Comment: Maybe it's somethin to do with your custom scripts.

Comment: thanks again! OMG something so easy and I spend so much time figuring out and tried to other ways but it was just at the tip of the eyes.

Comment: :) I am happy to help you. Happy coding :)