# Bootstrap JavaScript does not toggle tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I read the Bootstrap [Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/), the [Navs and tabs page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/), this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37289163/881712) and many other, still I cannot figure out what is my mistake.

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-target="#tabSystems" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" type="button" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabSystems"><i class="bi-gear"></i> Systems</button>
  <button class="nav-link" data-bs-target="#tabUpgrades"><i class="bi-download" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabUpgrades"></i> Upgrades</button>
</div>


<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tabSystems" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel">
    aaaaa
  </div>
  <div id="tabUpgrades" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
    bbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the tabs does not toggle.
From what I learnt:

- include JQuery *before* Bootstrap: done
- set `data-bs-toggle` and `data-bs-target`: done
- use classes like `nav-link`, `tab-pane`, etc... : done

What still am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't easy to spot but you have an error on your second button

you put `data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabUpgrades"` into the `<i>` tag

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <button class="nav-link active" data-bs-target="#tabSystems" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" type="button" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tabSystems"><i class="bi-gear"></i> Systems</button>
  <button class="nav-link" data-bs-target="#tabUpgrades" data-bs-toggle="tab" role="tab" type="button" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tabUpgrades"><i class="bi-download" ></i> Upgrades</button>
</div>


<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tabSystems" class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel">
    aaaaa
  </div>
  <div id="tabUpgrades" class="tab-pane fade" role="tabpanel">
    bbbbb
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to debug this kind of issues or we have just to rely on our eyes?

Comment: @Mark it's pretty hard to debug since it's plain html. You can try to search if someone implement some sort of XSD for validation but I'm not sure that it will solve this kind of issue